# Error al actualizar combobox anidados en PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Actualmente estoy en el diseño de un formulario que intento actualizar los campos, el problema que tengo es que uso combos anidados **(category_id y sub_categoria)** y al actualizar no me toma los valores de mi campo sub_categoria y por ende en la actualización se inserta vacío en la base de datos y no el ID correspondiente.

**Tabla sub_catagoria**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Formulario**
[image]

**upd_solicitud.php**

```js
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// Parametros para e combo1
$("#mod_category_id").change(function () {
$("#mod_category_id option:selected").each(function () {
 //alert($(this).val());
elegido=$(this).val();
$.post("mod_category_id.php", { elegido: elegido }, function(data){
$("#mod_subcategoria_id").html(data);
});         
   });
  })
});

</script>





<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">CATEGORÍA<span class="required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
<select class="form-control" name="mod_category_id" id="mod_category_id">   
            <option value="0">-- Selecciona --</option>
            <?php
            $db = new MySQL();  
            $db->open();
            $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY name ASC");
            if ($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta)) {
            do {
            echo 
            '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[name].'</option>';
            }while($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta));
            }
            ?> 
            </select>
</div>
</div>
                        
                        

                        
                        
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">SUB CATEGORÍA<span class="required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
<select  class="form-control" name="mod_subcategoria_id" id="mod_subcategoria_id">  
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

**COMBO mod_category_id.php**

```html
<?php
include("includes/config.inc.php");
include("includes/mysql.class.php");
$db = new MySQL();  
$db->open();
$consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM sub_categoria WHERE category_id LIKE '$_POST[elegido]'");
if ($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta)) {
    do {
        echo 
        '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }while($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta));
}
?>
```

**COMBO subcategoria_id.php**

```html
<?php
include "Conexion.php";
$db=connect();
$query=$db->query("select * from jefe where id_area=$_GET[combo1]");
$states = array();
while($r=$query->fetch_object()){ $states[]=$r; }
if(count($states)>0){
print "<option value=''>-- SELECCIONE --</option>";
foreach ($states as $s) {
    print "<option value='$s->id'>$s->name</option>";
}
}else{
print "<option value=''>-- NO HAY DATOS --</option>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="departamento" id="departamento" onchange="mmunicipios()">
  <option id="id">nombre_opcion</option>
</select>
```

// esta funcion es la que obtiene la lista de municipios asociados a un departamento(estado)

```
function mmunicipios(){
    //var result = false;
    const parametros = {
     "id_depto" : $("#departamento").val(),
  };
    
    $.ajax({
   data: parametros, 
   url: 'archivomunicipios.php', 
   type: 'post',
   beforeSend: function(){
    // quitarCargador();
   }, 
   success: function(response){
         if(!response.error) {
            const municipio = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = '';
            municipio.forEach(municipio => {
              template += `
                            <option value="${municipio.id_municipio}">${municipio.municipio}</option>
                    ` 
            });
            $('#municipios').html(template);
          }
   }
});

/// archivo php que recibe municipios
    if(isset($_POST['id_depto'])) {
        $conexion = conectar(); 
      $id = $_POST['id_depto'];
      $query = "select * from municipios where id_depto = '$id'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
      if (!$result) {
            echo "Ocurrio un error al mostrar mensaje"; 
        die('Query Failed.');
      }
        $json = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id_municipio = $row['id_municipio'];
        $municipio = $row['municipio']; 
                $json[] = array(
                    'id_municipio' => $id_municipio,
                    'municipio' => $municipio
                );
            }
            $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
            echo $jsonstring;
    }
```